# unable to write code in the main activity java file in android studio

Tags: android

After upgrade to ver 4.1.1, I am not able to write code in the MainActivity.java and the code is not editable in Android Studio. How can I correct it?

Comment: can you please share an image of what type of error you are getting

Comment: No error message. But when key pressed letters are not typed in the window .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem faced has been solved by reverting Android Studio to its default settings.

Answer (score 1):

If I am not wrong when you click on any line in the source code, the lines get highlighted but the caret indicator is not showing and the code is not editable.

I have faced the same problem many times and tried
After `File` -> `Invalidate` `Caches/Restart` the problem has been solved.

Comment: File ->Invalidate Caches/restart not solved the problem in my case  .I am using windows10 with AMD processor laptop. The XML and java code in the editor window can not be edited and not able to make fresh entry.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing this exact same problem. I solved it by pressing the <kbd>Insert</kbd> key once—apparently, I had inadvertently toggled Insert/Overwrite mode, and that was preventing me from editing code.